# Main-Class could not be found, despite it beeing there with the correct path

Tags: java, jar

I am creating a small project, and couldnt get past this problem, even tho numerous outhers have asked the question.

```
C:\Users\User\JavaProjects\Analyzertool>jar -tf Analyzingtool.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
src/calc.class
```

and

META-INF/MANIFEST:

```
Manifest-Version: 2.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_91 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: src/calc
```

And yet is sais:

```
C:\Users\User\JavaProjects\Analyzertool>java -jar Analyzingtool.jar
Error: Main-Class src.calc could not be found or loaded
```

Am i missing something? i followed the docs.oracle.
com guide and read multiple similar questions, but all the answers never resolved my problem

Comment: Is your class actually in a package called `src`?

Comment: `src` Folder ishould not be a part of the jar. remove it.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworthi do believe so. 1st the -tf shows it in src/calc.class and if i look at the jar with a zip-programm the clac.class is in src/ as well

Comment: What does the source code for `calc` look like? If it doesn't contain a `package` declaration for `src` (which would be unconventional, just like the name `calc`) then both your manifest and your jar file are broken.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah damn. indeed thank you. i forgot to put the package line into the calc.class. thank you

Comment: No, you built your .jar file wrongly. It should be based at the package root, not the `src` directory. Whatever the package root is, say `mypackage`, should be under the `src` directory, and should be mentioned in the `package` statement in the source code, and the `Main-class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the complete name of your class is `src.calc`, the correct class name format in the MANIFEST should be:

```
Main-Class: src.calc
```

(with period, not slash).

Comment: And without the .class. But `src` is unlikely to be part of a package name.

Comment: @EJP Look at the jar's contents.

Comment: It's part of the folder. That doesn't entail that it's part of the package name.

Comment: @EJP Well, assuming the jar file has been built by the `jar` tool, it does mean "src" is the package.

Comment: @EJP Nevertheless, I've updated my answer to assert my assumptions.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that at all. The only thing that determines that is the package statement in the .java file. It may well *be* in the `src` package, but at present there is no evidence to that effect.

Comment: @EJP There's no evidence neither that the package is not named "src".

Comment: But it's unlikely, which is what I actually said. OP has subsequently disclosed that he didn't have a package statement at all. QED.

Comment: Ah, that's different. I didn't see that. Thanks.